# SQL - List those that DON'T match

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've written the following query, but I've realised that I need it to do the opposite of what it's currently doing.

I need to display everyone that has a payroll_no in UG, where the number doesn't exsist in esr.

```
select distinct ug.name, ug.payroll_no, esr.assignment 
from user_group as ug
inner join esrtraining as esr 
on ug.payroll_no = SUBSTRING(esr.assignment,2,8)
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this. This utilises `LEFT JOIN` which brings everything in `ug` table followed by `WHERE` clause which filters and brings only those records which did not satisfy the match criteria

```
select distinct ug.name, ug.payroll_no, esr.assignment 
from user_group as ug
LEFT join esrtraining as esr 
on ug.payroll_no = SUBSTRING(esr.assignment,2,8) 
WHERE 
esr.assignment is NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do a `LEFT JOIN` which will leave all `esr` fields as `NULL`. From there, you may simply filter that result with `WHERE esr.assignment IS NULL`.

For this reason, `esr.assignment` will of course always be null in your select.

Answer (score 1):

The way you phrase the question is a good way to solve it:  use `not exists`:

```
select ug.name, ug.payroll_no
from user_group as ug
where not exists (select 1
                  from esrtraining as esr 
                  where ug.payroll_no = SUBSTRING(esr.assignment, 2, 8)
                 );
```

The distinct shouldn't be necessary, unless you have duplicates in `user_group`.